# unable to fetch json attribute in POST request

Tags: python, json, post, bottle

This Json is received as a POST request. Now
I want to get value of `text` key of each entry in `actions` array

I am using Python's Bottle to receive the request.
to fetch the value of required attribute, I did this

```
word = request.forms.get('[attachments][actions][0][text]')
```

But this doesn't print required value.

```
{
  "attachments": [
    {
      "title": "XYZ",
      "title_link": "EDWE",
      "text": "dxjhvgebndm",
      "fields": [
        {
          "title": "Food",
          "value": "$20",
          "short": true
        }
      ],
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "chess",
          "text": "Approve",
          "type": "button",
          "value": "chess",
          "style": "primary"
        },
        {
          "name": "maze",
          "text": "Decline",
          "style": "danger",
          "type": "button",
          "value": "maze"
        },
        {
          "name": "war",
          "text": "More details",
          "style": "default",
          "type": "button",
          "value": "war",
          "confirm": {
            "title": "Are you sure?",
            "text": "Would you like to see more details of your expense?",
            "ok_text": "Yes",
            "dismiss_text": "No"
          }
        }
      ],
      "image_url": "",
      "thumb_url": "https://i.imgsafe.org/cf40eef.png",
      "footer": "fghj",
      "footer_icon": "https://i.imgsafe.org/cf2e0eef.png",
      "ts": 1475057533
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: I am receiving complete JSON, the problem is in fetching correct attribute.

**EDIT**
Through this i am receiving POST request

```
import json
from bottle import route, run, request
import urllib

@route('/ocr_response', method='POST')
def ocr_response():
    body = request.body.read()
    word = request.forms.get('[attachments][actions][0][text]')
    print word
    print body


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

Comment: attachments is an array, but your get seems completely wrong anyway

Comment: You are trying to read json from the body? The why you are using `request.forms.get` instead of parsing `body` as JSON?

Comment: Ohh shit, I could have directly parsed the body as JSON
seriously my bad

Comment: thanks @cricket_007

Comment: What's inside request.forms?

Comment: I would like to believe that the below answer is correct as well. I haven't used Bottle though

Answer (score 3):

That's not how you access items in a dictionary at all.

Firstly, the JSON data is available via `request.json`. Secondly, I'm not sure what you're doing with that string you're passing to get, but you need to use normal dictionary/array syntax. And thirdly, attachments is a list just like actions, so you'd need to add an index there too.

```
request.json['attachments'][0]['actions'][0]['text']
```

Comment: No no you took it wrong, can you please see edit I made just now

Comment: I know how to read JSON, dictionary everything
the problem I am facing is reading the same dictionary in my `POST` request, which access values using `request.forms.get()`

Comment: @Guru I have no idea how your edit changes my answer. That is *not* how you access nested dictionaries, as evidenced by the fact that your code isn't working.